# String convertion using regex

Tags: regex

How to convert

```
date BETWEEN '01-Oct-2017' && '02-Oct-2017' && id==100
```

to

```
date >= '01-Oct-2017' && date <= '02-Oct-2017' && id==100
```

using regular expressions?

Basically I need to convert for dates.

Comment: `I need to convert for dates` ... your date literals are in a non ISO format both before and after.  Why are you using this date format?  Also, using which tool would you be doing the regex replacement?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to repeat the variable `date` for the second comparison?

Comment: it is almost the most basic situation of regex replace using group.  Have you even tried something?  And you should be clear on how the match is supposed to be done instead of us guess it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker. sorry, my bad. Yes, Date is required for the second comparison. And I'm using javascript

Comment: @AdrianShum. Yes I tried using .replace().

Comment: "tried something" : I mean at least have you tried to do some basic study on regex?

Comment: @AdrianShum. See no one knows everything. If you can help, its appreciated. Else you can continue on your work. Don't waste ur time

Comment: I agree no one knows everything.  However, when you come to SO to ask question, you need to know what SO is about.  It is a community-managed site, so we all have obligation to voice out if the question is not properly asked.  And, SO is a place for you to ask specific programming problem.  It is NOT a place for you to throw out the requirement and expect for the code.

Comment: what u mean by the question not properly asked. It was straightforward question. And every requirement has its own importance. Please try to understand that. And after trying for couple of times, I put this question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  , for the off-topic section, point 1 and 3  .  And, given it is a regex problem, and you claimed you have tried couple of times, shouldn't you attach the regex-es you tried and what doesn't work?  Again, SO is not a place for you to "throw out the requirement and expect for the code"

Answer (score 0):

For your example (which hopefully is representative of everything you need to match), you can search for

```
date BETWEEN ('[^']*') && ('[^']*')
```

and replace with

```
date <= \1 && date >= \2
```

The exact syntax depends on the language you're using (please always tag the language in regex questions).

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9wVDLo/1/).

Comment: Im using Javascript